# Compose Lottie component doesn't work properly if you don't cover it with Card

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I want to have a Lottie file in column, but lottie file comes over other controls, I could fix the problem with putting lottie file inside the card

See the example

```
@Composable
fun TileAnimation(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Card {
        Column {
            Text(
                text = "headline",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )

            val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.lottielogo))
//            Card(
//                modifier = Modifier
//                    .height(183.dp)
//                    .then(modifier),
//                shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
//            ) {
            LottieAnimation(
                composition = composition,
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(183.dp),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            )
//            }
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Button(
                    onClick = { }, modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                        .wrapContentSize()
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result as you see the text is covered ->
[image]

And if you uncomment the card part then it looks fine ->
[image]

Kotlin version 1.6.10 and compose 1.1.0 and this is lottie library ->

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:4.2.2"
```

BTW, you can download Lottie file from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXwaN.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXwaN.png): https://lottiefiles.com/96036-bored-cat

I want to ask my solution is right, or you guys suggest another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All views in Compose by default are not clip to bounds.

`contentScale = ContentScale.Crop` only determines scaling.

To clip content to the view size, specified by other modifiers, add `Modifier.clip(RectangleShape)` to your view.